# calling overridden subclass's class method from abstract superclass

Tags: objective-c, oop, polymorphism

Supposing I have an abstract superclass (e.g., 'Shape') and it has two subclasses (e.g., 'Circle' and 'Triangle').  Shape has a class method which is overridden in Circle and Triangle.  If I want any given Shape to call this method on itself, but I don't know which subclass will be calling the method until runtime, how can I call it?  E.g.,

```
@implementation Shape
 +(void)iAmA{
NSLog(@"I'm an abstract method");
}

-(void)identifySelf {
    [???? iAmA];  //call relevant subclass's class method
}
@end
```

and

```
@implementation Triangle
 +(void)iAmA{
    NSLog(@"I'm a triangle");
}
@end

@implementation Circle
 +(void)iAmA{
     NSLog(@"I'm a circle");
 }
 @end
```

So, an instance of a Shape subclass should be able to call identifySelf, and make use of it's own class's iAmA method.  In Swift, I would do this with the Self keyword.  How can I do this in Objective-C?  (Thanks, and please let me know if I need to clarify the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)identifySelf {
    [[self class] iAmA];
}
```